# Syntax for using toEpochDate with a Dataframe with Spark Scala - elegantly

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The following is nice and easy with an RDD in terms of epochDate derivation:

```
val rdd2 = rdd.map(x => (x._1, x._2, x._3,
                         LocalDate.parse(x._2.toString).toEpochDay, LocalDate.parse(x._3.toString).toEpochDay))
```

The RDD are all of String Type. The desired result is gotten. Get this, for example:

```
...(Mike,2018-09-25,2018-09-30,17799,17804), ...
```

Trying to do the same if there is a String in the DF appears too tricky for me, and I would like to see something elegant, if possible. Something like this and variations do not work.

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("s", $"start".LocalDate.parse.toString.toEpochDay)
```

Get:

```
notebook:50: error: value LocalDate is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName
```

I understand the error, but what is an elegant way of doing the conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$"start"` is of type `ColumnName` not `String`.

You will need to define a UDF

Example below:

```
scala> import java.time._
import java.time._

scala> def toEpochDay(s: String) = LocalDate.parse(s).toEpochDay
toEpochDay: (s: String)Long

scala> val toEpochDayUdf = udf(toEpochDay(_: String))
toEpochDayUdf: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,LongType,Some(List(StringType)))

scala> val df = List("2018-10-28").toDF
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> df.withColumn("s", toEpochDayUdf($"value")).collect
res0: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([2018-10-28,17832])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define `to_epoch_day` as `datediff` since the beginning of the epoch:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{datediff, lit, to_date}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def to_epoch_day(c: Column) = datediff(c, to_date(lit("1970-01-01")))
```

and apply it directly on a `Column`:

```scala
df.withColumn("s", to_epoch_day(to_date($"start")))
```

As long as the string format complies with ISO 8601 you could even skip data conversion (it will be done implicitly by `datediff`:

```scala
df.withColumn("s", to_epoch_day($"start"))
```